# Gift Card Issue

Tags: iphone, itunes, itunes-store

I have an issue with my iTunes gift card ...

I try purchasing an iPhone with my gift card. When it got to proceed with payment, I input my credit/debit card details and gift card pin which it accepts.

When I proceed it shows an error message:

> You have reached the maximum number of attempts. Please choose another payment method.

What should I do?

Comment: Each online store had [dedicated help for pre-purchase support](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/292910/5472). Are you shopping here? https://www.apple.com/store

Comment: Also, if it is urgent, just do as the message says and use another payment method :-)